# How to create a installer for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation

is there any tool to create something like an Installer for `Ubuntu` as there is for `Windows`?

Answer (score 6):

If you're after the equivalent of an .msi , then a .deb file is what you want.
If necessary you can make it interactive using an install-time script (`preinst` or `postinst`).

**.deb files**

A deb is just a zip archive (named xxx.deb), having a particular structure including the software itself and some metadata. Metadata includes things like 'dependencies', so you don't need to ship 3rd-party tooling (e.g. python libraries or a database engine).

There are many ways of building debs, and your toolchain for building your software may have a plugin for this (e.g. Maven is a Java build tool which has a .deb plugin)

Here are some starting points:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete (see 'binary packages')
- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html
- `pbuilder` is a tool recommended by Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto

**Interactive installers**

If you're after an interactive installer, you could use 'debconf' to provide some simple inputs, to be run inside your `preinst` or `postinst` script. (e.g. mysql-server uses debconf)
http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html

---

**IzPack**

Alternatively, if you're interested in a cross-platform GUI installer, and you are happy to use a Java-based tool, then you might want to look at IzPack. IzPack is mainly for packaging Java apps, but it can be used for non-java software aswell.

http://izpack.org/

Answer (score 3):

The [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide) should have all the information you need. Basically you could just provide the binary if that's all you program needs, but even then making a .deb would handle e.g. copying it to the proper location for the user. If you want your package to be available directly from the repositories you will have to request that. I'm not sure what the guidlines for that are in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

to zip & pack compiled file I think not and it is pointless to have one.

if you want to pack your own software best method is to put an shell script inside it and put compile commands and get inputs from user inside it. name it as install.sh and zip it in a "tar.gz" format.